# how do I speed up this ugly query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, search

I'm trying to show a user other users that have companies/skills/schools on their profile that the current user is following. Once the list of users who have such attributes on their profile is created, I'd like to sort it by the count of relevant companies/skills/schools associated with each returned user to display the most relevant users on the top of the list.

Although this works, it is very ugly and predictably slow, and I'm not sure where to start cleaning it up. A few pointers would be appreciated.

```
def term_helper(terms,user)
  relevant_terms = []
  terms.each do |term|
    if user.positions.any? { |w| w.company.downcase.include?(term.downcase) rescue nil || w.industry.downcase.include?(term.downcase) rescue nil }
      relevant_terms << term
    end
    if user.educations.any? { |w| w.school.downcase.include?(term.downcase) rescue nil }
      relevant_terms << term
    end
    if user.held_skills.any? { |w| w.name.downcase.include?(term.downcase) rescue nil } 
      relevant_terms << term
    end
  end
  relevant_terms
end

def search
  if current_user
    followed_companies = current_user.followed_companies.pluck(:name)
    followed_skills = current_user.followed_skills.pluck(:name)
    @terms = (followed_companies + followed_skills).uniq
    full_list = []
    full_list_with_terms = {}
    users = []
    @terms.each do |term|
      full_list += User.text_search(term).uniq
      # using pg_search gem here
    end
    full_list.each_with_index do |user,index|
      terms = term_helper(@terms,user)
      full_list_with_terms[index] = {"user" => user, "term_count" => terms.count}
    end
    full_list_with_terms = full_list_with_terms.sort_by {|el| el[1]["term_count"]}
    full_list_with_terms.each do |el|
      users << el[1]["user"]
    end
    @matches = users.uniq.reverse.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pointers:

1. What does the `User.text_search` method do? Are you using a fulltext search engine? If so, you should construct one search query (`term1 OR term2 OR term3` etc) instead of kicking off a separate search for every term.
2. In the `User.text_search` method, are you creating database joins to pre-fetch educations, positions, held_skills and their companies, schools and skill names? That would greatly reduce the number of database queries.
3. Consider [denormalizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271532/activerecord-denormalization-case-study) your database schema. Maybe you can add a `company_name` column to your `positions` table, a `school_name` column to your `educations` and a `skill_name` column to your `held_skills` table. That would greatly simplify your queries and improve performance.

Those would be a few starting points.